# Which line should PHP files in Joomla start with?

Tags: php, joomla-4.x, security

I know, that the first line in PHP Files is because of security reasons. I read it here: https://docs.joomla.org/Why_do_most_of_the_Joomla!_PHP_files_start_with_defined(%27_JEXEC%27)%3F

But in the Joomla Core Code I find different commands. For example:

`\defined('JPATH_PLATFORM') or die;`,

`\defined('JPATH_BASE') or die;`

and

`\defined('_JEXEC') or die;`

Which line should PHP files in Joomla start with?

Answer (score 3):

It makes no difference when used in extensions. But if you want to be technically correct, `_JEXEC` is the one to use. It's declared earliest, in the entry point file (i.e. `index.php`), and its sole purpose is for performing this entry point check. Other global constants may generally work but it's not really their purpose.

Also, `JPATH_PLATFORM` is deprecated as of 4.4 so definitely don't use that.